# What does $|λ,μ\rangle$ mean in Dirac notation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, notation

[image: Screenshot of notation]My guess is that it's shorthand for Ψ<sub>λ,μ</sub> but I've never seen it written like this before. Here is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGvfqRfw1BE&list=PL8W2boV7eVfmm5SZRjbhOKNziRXy6yIvI&index=2) in question discussing ladder operators with respect to angular momentum. At 12:24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\lambda, \mu \rangle$ is a vector which is an eigenstate both of the $J^2$ operator and the $J_3$ operator, with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$, respectively. It is one possible state of the system, so it is generally normalized etc. just like any wave function would be.

Comment: So in general terms: For any wavefunction denoted |a,b,c>, a,b, and c refer to the eigenvalues that can be measured simultaneously from the wavefunction |a,b,c>. Also implying that a,b and c all commute with each other. Is this correct?

Comment: @Dutonic Yep exactly!

Comment: Strictly speaking it is the operators corresponding to a, b, and c that commute with each other, not the eigenvalues themselves (all eigenvalues commute as they are just numbers). But I think that is what you meant. The reason we label a state by more than one eigenvalue is because sometimes there is more than one state with a particular EV. In your example there are many states with the eigenvalue of $J^2$ equal to a particular value, but by specifying the eigenvalue of $J_3$ as well we narrow it down to one state... at least within the context of what you were watching.